# Testing Ansible-Roles using Ansible Tower

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-role, molecule

I'm starting a new project and the client uses Ansible Tower. I will be working on Playbook/Role development and will need to do extensive testing. My question is: Does Ansible Tower support testing with Molecule and if so, where can I find documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we're talking about 2 different things here, Ansible tower is used to run Ansible playbooks (with their roles), so consider it as your target in your CD.

For Molecule Tests, you need to check where is your CI and add the tests there.

You could implement that but by setting up a Jenkins server for your CI, where each commits or merges request you execute a couple of steps such as linting, molecule tests, and if all good you deploy the playbooks to ansible tower using its API (CD).

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for the response.